# Find all the documents that has same subdocuments mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have postSchema which references the tagsSchema.

```
 var tagsSchem = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// create a schema
var postsSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    mainImage: {
        type: String
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    tags: [tagsSchem]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

One post can contain any no. of tags. So if a post has 3 tags then I want to get all the posts with those 3 tags without querying it multiple times. Is it possible?

Comment: all the posts that has **one** of these three tags or **all** three tags together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform find, you can use the `$in` option to find values that are in your array. For example:

```
posts.find({tags:{$in:{["tag1","tag2","tag3"]}}, function(err,data) {
... //Your code here
}
```

This will take all the posts that contains one of the three tags. It's important you have to pass an array in the `$in` option. This should work.

Comment: Suppose if I just have the post id and not all the tags. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe it will return nothing

Comment: should I use the tag id's or the names in $in array

Comment: It depends of what you have as reference in the post schema. If you are persisting the ids, you should search for ids, if you are persisting the names, you should search for the names.

Comment: So If i just have postId there is no way to get all the related posts without the above solution?

Comment: If you have only the postId, how would relate it to other posts?

Comment: Just by tagsSchema

Comment: So, you have a postId, then you'll retrieve the tagIds from this post and then search by the tagIds, right?

Comment: Yes, From the postId I will get the Post then the tags. If it's not possible I will do this way only